# Is it possible to create custom Parsers in Boost.Spirit?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I was trying to create a custom Parser class in Boost.Spirit (2.3), but it didn't work out. The code is:

```
template <class Iter>
class crule : public boost::spirit::qi::parser<crule<Iter> >
{
  rule<Iter> r_;
public:
  crule(const rule<Iter>& r) : r_(r) {}
  template <class T>
  crule(const T& t) : r_(t) {}
  template<class Ctx, class Skip>
  bool parse(Iter& f, const Iter& l, Ctx& context, Skip& skip, typename rule<Iter>::template attribute<Ctx, Iter>::type& attr) const {
    return r_.parse(f, l, context, skip, attr);
  }
  template <class Ctx>
  boost::spirit::info what(Ctx& context) const {
    return r_.what(context);
  }
  template <class Context, class It>
  struct attribute {
    typedef typename rule<Iter>::template attribute<Context, It>::type type;
  };
};
```

and although I have (at least I think I have) fulfilled all the [requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/parser.html), I get errors when I try to use this class in a parsing expression:

```
shell_grammar.h:134: error: no match for 'operator!' in '!shell_grammar<Iter>::token(boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iter, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type>) [with Iter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >](boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type>(((const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type>&)((const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type>*)(&((shell_grammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >*)this)->shell_grammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::reserved_words)))))'

shell_grammar.h:134: note: candidates are: operator!(bool) <built-in>
```

I tried to look at the implementation of other parsets (eg. `not_predicate`), but can't figure out what is the difference that makes it work.

### Motvation

The reason I do it is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470668/copy-or-reference-semantics-of-boostspirits-rule). I want to parse POSIX shell language, which has peculiar lexical rules. Particularly, the "skipper parser" has to be applied even in lexemes, but it has to be different from the "phrase level" skipper parser. Which is what the `lexeme` directive can't do, and `skip` doesn't pre-skip (AFAIK), which is what I need, too. So I want to create a function

```
something token(std::string);
```

that would return a rule matching the token. One way is creating my own `rule` wrapper that would serve as a terminal (since `rule` alone cannot be used for its reference semantics), another would be creating a new parser (that would be a nonterminal in `proto`), and implement shell's token parsing in it.

Comment: WOW !!!!! the first error line is more than 550 characters... Wow... Wow...

Comment: @Stephane Rolland: Actually, this is not that exceptional. I regularly get even longer lines, and this one could be interpreted as "Operator ! cannot be applied to `crule`", the point is, it can be applied to spirit rules and parsers and I can't find out how do they do it (they don't implement `operator!`, but use some Boost.Proto magic).

Comment: have you tried compiling and linking at Full and New Moon only ?

Comment: That error line is sadly not at all atypical of what you can get from very simple errors in a Spirit specification. As I mentioned below, if you aren't comfortable with such things (or worse), then you probably shouldn't be using Spirit. After a couple of projects, I decided I'm in that category.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite possible, but I have found it to be as much work (and harder to debug) than just writing my own lexers and recursive descent parsers by hand. Even fairly small Spirit grammars can take me weeks of wrestling with the compiler.

This error message you got shows the kind of problems you run into. Any time you get an error, its an error from some template instantiation down deep in the bowels of Spirit, with many further layers of template instatiations added in to confuse matters. In order to have any hope of deciphering the error messages, you pretty much have to understand the code for the entire facility.

I hate to be critical, because Spirit is a worthy effort. I did my Master's thesis on implementing an [object-oriented compiler-generator](http://stephe-leake.org/ada/opentoken.html), so I'm a fan of the concept. I really wanted to like it, but Spirit is just too hard for anyone but serious C++ experts to use.

To compare with what can be done, take a look at the Ada [OpenToken](http://stephe-leake.org/ada/opentoken.html) project. Spirit is probably more flexible, but compile errors are much more sensible in OpenToken, and a glance through the version history on that page shows a very large percentage of their effort has been put into helping users debug errors.

Comment: I really hope that Boost.MPL, Spirit, StateChart, Prototype etc will make use of static_assert (or BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG) to convey nicer errors messages. Of course, it would be nice if c++ itself had a way to substitute your error message when something went wrong. (i'd settle just for gcc having some nice #pragmas to do that)

Answer (score 3):

The code you provided looks ok (at least as far as the interface of the actual parser is concerned). But in order to integrate a custom parser with Spirit you need to do more work. Spirit's website has an example for a custom parser component explaining all required steps [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/creating-your-own-parser-component-for-spirit-qi/).

It looks to me as if you were unnecessarily trying to do things the hard way. But I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, so I might be wrong. If you explained your use case I'm sure we could come up with a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link; I have noticed the Proto magic and tried something with Proto, however, it takes aaaaaggggggeeeeeeessssssss to compile and I got segfaults so I have to work on it further. I may post what I have come to here if I happen to debug it.

Comment: Note that I have found some problems in the code I posted; I'll edit it so it doesn't spread confusion.

Answer (score 1):

BTW this is what I came up to:

You need to register the class as a literal in `boost::proto` like this:

```
template <class T>
struct crulexx : public boost::proto::literal<rule<T> >
{
  template <class U>
  crulexx(const U& u) : boost::proto::literal<rule<T> >(rule<T>(u)) {}
};
```

It works for me in this [test](http://pastebin.org/617260). However, I got segfaults in other piece of code using it, which I will have to debug.

Comment: Just look at the example I gave you the link for, then all mystery should go away. But I'm still unsure what you're up to - dare to explain?

Comment: @hkaiser: Yes, see edit. BTW, you propose making the new parser a nonterminal in spirit's `proto` grammar, is that beneficial over making it a terminal?

Comment: Where did I mention non-terminals? Generally, writing new parsers is easier if those are terminals (and most of the time that's sufficient). If you feel you need a new non-terminal, try to use rule<> directly first.