# boost::spirit::qi::grammar and variadic templates

Tags: c++, parsing, variadic-templates, boost-spirit-qi

I'm facing with an issue in defining a grammar with variadic templates.

I started by defining some simple grammars contained into some struct (e.g. Latitude, Longitude) as follows:

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::spirit;

template <class Attribute>
using command_rule =
    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, Attribute, ascii::space_type>;

template <class Attribute>
using command_grammar =
    qi::grammar<std::string::iterator, Attribute, ascii::space_type>;

struct Latitude {

  struct return_type {
    double lat_;
  };

  struct grammar : command_grammar<return_type()> {
    grammar() : grammar::base_type{latitude_} {
      latitude_ = "LAT=" >> qi::double_;
    }

  private:
    command_rule<return_type()> latitude_;
  };
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Latitude::return_type, (double, lat_))

struct Longitude {

  struct return_type {
    double lon_;
  };

  struct grammar : command_grammar<return_type()> {
    grammar() : grammar::base_type{longitude_} {
      longitude_ = "LON=" >> qi::double_;
    }

  private:
    command_rule<return_type()> longitude_;
  };
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Longitude::return_type, (double, lon_))
```

Then, I would like to combine them in a complete grammar that is able to parse strings belonging to any of these simple grammars. To to this, I have defined a variadic template struct that tries to expand a list of sub-grammars into an expression like "grammar1 | grammar2 | ..."

```
template <class... Commands>
struct device_grammar : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<
                            std::string::iterator,
                            boost::variant<typename Commands::return_type...>(),
                            boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> {

  typedef boost::variant<typename Commands::return_type...> return_type;

  device_grammar() : device_grammar::base_type{rule_}{
    build_rule<typename Commands::grammar...>();
  }

private:

  template <class CommandGrammar> void build_rule() {
    rule_ = CommandGrammar();
  }

  template <class FirstGrammar, class SecondGrammar, class... Others>
  void build_rule() {
    build_rule<SecondGrammar, Others...>();
    rule_ = rule_ | FirstGrammar();
  }

  boost::spirit::qi::rule<std::string::iterator, return_type(),
                          boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>
      rule_;
};

typedef device_grammar<Latitude, Longitude> CoordinatesGrammar;
```

The code compiles (see the complete example below); the problem is that when it try to parse the input string, a segmentation fault is generated.
Can someone please help me to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EXAMPLE CODE (g++-4.9 or clang++-3.9):**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class... Commands>
struct device_grammar : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<
                            std::string::iterator,
                            boost::variant<typename Commands::return_type...>(),
                            boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> {

  typedef boost::variant<typename Commands::return_type...> return_type;

  device_grammar() : device_grammar::base_type{rule_}{
    build_rule<typename Commands::grammar...>();
  }

private:

  template <class CommandGrammar> void build_rule() {
    rule_ = CommandGrammar();
  }

  template <class FirstGrammar, class SecondGrammar, class... Others>
  void build_rule() {
    build_rule<SecondGrammar, Others...>();
    rule_ = rule_ | FirstGrammar();
  }

  boost::spirit::qi::rule<std::string::iterator, return_type(),
                          boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>
      rule_;
};

using namespace boost::spirit;

template <class Attribute>
using command_rule =
    qi::rule<std::string::iterator, Attribute, ascii::space_type>;

template <class Attribute>
using command_grammar =
    qi::grammar<std::string::iterator, Attribute, ascii::space_type>;

struct Latitude {

  struct return_type {
    double lat_;
  };

  struct grammar : command_grammar<return_type()> {
    grammar() : grammar::base_type{latitude_} {
      latitude_ = "LAT=" >> qi::double_;
    }

  private:
    command_rule<return_type()> latitude_;
  };
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Latitude::return_type, (double, lat_))

struct Longitude {

  struct return_type {
    double lon_;
  };

  struct grammar : command_grammar<return_type()> {
    grammar() : grammar::base_type{longitude_} {
      longitude_ = "LON=" >> qi::double_;
    }

  private:
    command_rule<return_type()> longitude_;
  };
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Longitude::return_type, (double, lon_))

typedef device_grammar<Latitude, Longitude> CoordinatesGrammar;

struct print : public boost::static_visitor<> {

  void operator()(Latitude::return_type &t) const {
    std::cout << "Latitude = " << t.lat_ << " deg" << std::endl;
    ;
  }

  void operator()(Longitude::return_type &t) const {
    std::cout << "Longitude = " << t.lon_ << " deg" << std::endl;
    ;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::string s;

  CoordinatesGrammar g;
  CoordinatesGrammar::return_type v;
  while (1) {
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    auto it = s.begin();
    if (qi::phrase_parse(it, s.end(), g, ascii::space, v)) {
      print p;
      boost::apply_visitor(p, v);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
As far as I understand, the problem is in the lines

```
rule_ = CommandGrammar();
...
rule_ = rule_ | FirstGrammar();
```

It seems that the grammar objects can not be temporary and have to be stored as members of the class. How can I do that?

**EDIT:**
I have also tried to store such objects in a `std::tuple`, but it seems still not working.

Comment: Try using `rule_ = rule_.copy() |...` in addition to storing the grammars in a tuple.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Can you explain me what was the issue?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20158897/2417774) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3470668/2417774) may help.

Comment: @llonesmiz or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405500/c-boost-qi-recursive-rule-construction or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812715/boost-qi-composing-rules-using-functions. In this case, though, I'd simply use auto-parsers.

Comment: @llonesmiz added an answer showing that approach

Comment: @llonesmiz Oh and the X3 version of things too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are creating closely resembles what qi's auto parser already does: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auto.html

If you specialize [`create_parser<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/auto/create_parser.html) for your datatypes you can simply use `qi::auto_` straight-away:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7c427e5140547d1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace Commands {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    template <class T> using Rule = qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, T()>;

    template <typename... T>
    auto parse(std::string const& s) {
        boost::variant<T...> v;

        auto it = s.begin();
        if (qi::parse(it, s.end(), qi::auto_, v))
            return v;
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string(__FUNCTION__) + " failed");
    }
}

struct Latitude  { double lat_; };
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Latitude, lat_)

struct Longitude { double lon_; };
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Longitude, lon_)

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <> struct create_parser<Latitude> {
        using type = Commands::Rule<Latitude>;
        static type const& call() {
            static type const s_rule = qi::skip(qi::space)["LAT=" >> qi::auto_];
            return s_rule;
        };
    };

    template <> struct create_parser<Longitude> {
        using type = Commands::Rule<Longitude>;
        static type const& call() {
            static type const s_rule = qi::skip(qi::space)["LON=" >> qi::auto_];
            return s_rule;
        };
    };
} } }

struct print {
    using result_type = void;
    void operator()(Latitude const &t)  const { std::cout << "Latitude = " << t.lat_ << " deg" << std::endl; }
    void operator()(Longitude const &t) const { std::cout << "Longitude = " << t.lon_ << " deg" << std::endl; }
};

#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss("LAT=4.3\n LON=5.0");
    std::string s;

    print printer;

    while (std::getline(iss, s)) try {
        auto v = Commands::parse<Latitude, Longitude>(s);
        boost::apply_visitor(printer, v);
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "'" << s << "': " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Latitude = 4.3 deg
Longitude = 5 deg
```

### Nicer things

If you don't use `qi::rule<>` you don't need to hard-code the iterator either. Let's go full fun mode and get rid of the visitor too:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84f7a8c9a453fc1b</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace Commands {
    template <typename... T>
    auto parse(std::string const& s) {
        boost::variant<T...> v;

        auto it = s.begin();
        if (boost::spirit::qi::parse(it, s.end(), boost::spirit::qi::auto_, v))
            return v;
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string(__FUNCTION__) + " failed");
    }

    struct Latitude { double lat_; };
    struct Longitude { double lon_; };

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Latitude const &t) { return os << "Latitude = " << t.lat_ << " deg"; }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Longitude const &t) { return os << "Longitude = " << t.lon_ << " deg"; }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Commands::Latitude, lat_)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Commands::Longitude, lon_)

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    #define MAP_PARSER(T, expr) \
    template <> struct create_parser<T> { \
        using type = decltype(qi::attr_cast<T, T>(qi::copy(expr))); \
        static type const& call() { static type const s_rule = qi::attr_cast<T, T>(qi::copy(expr)); return s_rule; }; \
    };

    #define AUTO_MAP_PARSER(T, caption) MAP_PARSER(T, qi::skip(qi::space)[qi::lit(caption) >> '=' >> qi::auto_])

    AUTO_MAP_PARSER(::Commands::Longitude, "LON")
    AUTO_MAP_PARSER(::Commands::Latitude, "LAT")
} } }

#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss("LAT=4.3\n LON=5.0");
    std::string s;

    while (std::getline(iss, s)) try {
        using namespace Commands;
        std::cout << "Parsed '" << s << "' into " << parse<Latitude, Longitude>(s) << "\n";
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "'" << s << "': " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed 'LAT=4.3' into Latitude = 4.3 deg
Parsed ' LON=5.0' into Longitude = 5 deg
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is very interesting. What I am really trying to do is to invoke the `parse` function with only one template argument, so the need for a "container" of the various simple grammars.

Comment: Hmm? There you go: [minimal change](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba62008780ac94d4). Even if for some /other/ reason you really need a `qi::grammar` instance instead of `qi::auto_`, you can add it in ~3 lines of code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25253281/ ([x3 version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30e27f3fb039b9ee))

Answer (score 2):

> *In addition to the [Spirit Qi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45526550/85371) I gave:*

If you can afford to enable c++1z, you can use Spirit X3 with fold-expressions:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebf6443bdc9d120c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace Commands {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    template <typename... T>
    auto parse(std::string const& s) {
        using V = boost::variant<T...>;
        V v;

        auto it = s.begin();
        if (x3::parse(it, s.end(), parser_for(v), v))
            return v;
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string(__FUNCTION__) + " failed");
    }

    struct Latitude { double lat_; };
    struct Longitude { double lon_; };

    auto label_for(Latitude) { return "LAT"; }
    auto label_for(Longitude) { return "LON"; }

    template <typename T, typename P>
    auto as_cmd(P p) { return x3::rule<struct _, T>{} 
            = x3::skip(x3::space)[x3::lit(label_for(T{})) >> '=' >> p]; }

    template <typename T>    auto parser_for(T)                      { return as_cmd<T>(x3::double_); }
    template <typename... T> auto parser_for(boost::variant<T...> _) { return (parser_for(T{}) | ...); }

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Latitude const &t) { return os << "Latitude = " << t.lat_ << " deg"; }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Longitude const &t) { return os << "Longitude = " << t.lon_ << " deg"; }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Commands::Latitude, lat_)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Commands::Longitude, lon_)

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss("LAT=4.3\n LON=5.0");
    std::string s;

    while (std::getline(iss, s)) try {
        using namespace Commands;
        std::cout << "Parsed '" << s << "' into " << parse<Latitude, Longitude>(s) << "\n";
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "'" << s << "': " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed 'LAT=4.3' into Latitude = 4.3 deg
Parsed ' LON=5.0' into Longitude = 5 deg
```